# How add method decorator

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I want to create the method decorate in angular where I can pass the argument and it will override the result. For example let suppose I have calculation typescript file which look like below.

```
export class Calculation{
    @multiply(2)
    addOne(number:number) {
        return number+1;
    }        
}

function multiply(param1: number) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        // my code      
    };
}
```

and I have above "multiply" method decorator where I am passing the argument value as 2 when I will call `console.log(new Calculation().addOne(2))` it should return ((2+1)*2) = 6

Can anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: I don't think we could answer this any better than the documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators. What problem are you running into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your decorator looks like this, it returns the original result multiplied by two:

```
export function multiply(factor: number) {
  return function(target: Object, key: string | symbol, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    originalFunction = descriptor.value
    descriptor.value = (num: number) => {
      originalFunction.call(this as any, num) * factor;
      //                         ^^^^^^
    }
    return descriptor;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  @jigfor for the reply ,But this function is giving an error as  'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation. Can you please let me know how we can resolve this ?

Comment: make it an explicit `any`

Comment: @jigfox wouldn't you want to pass `target` in `originalFunction.call` as  `this`? What's the point of passing in the nested inner function there? I'd expect an instance of the original class to be `this`

Comment: yes you could pass `target`, it would have the same effect, but you need to be careful, this works differently on `static` methods`

Comment: Thanks @jigfox  To get the result , I modified the code where you pass "this as any" as "target" and return the original function as "return  originalFunction.call(target, num) * factor;" and it is giving the result which want in console.log(new Calculation().addOne(2))

Comment: I would suggest keeping `this` it's safer (ie you want to add this method to another prototype, than it could take another `this` than intended), and the typescript docs to so too: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html